# Django spaceless template tag advantages

Tags: django, html, django-templates

I've been wondering about this a lot recently, what is exactly the purpose of Django's [spaceless](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#spaceless) template tag?

Obviously it removes whitespaces from HTML tags, but other than that does it increase the speed at which the pages load?

What I mean to ask is, does removing whitespaces from html files help in any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A newline/space is a character, yes, and it will increase file size especially with large loops and human readability optimized template files (like a large FK list).

It's also exceedingly easy and safe to throw in {% spaceless %} in a base template.

It also lets you keep template code indented for readability but properly spaceless for HTML rendering (I'm thinking commas are a common scenario).

Comment: Thank you. I just wanted to be sure :)

Comment: It can affect how things look.  If you have `<strong>X</strong> <a href="#">Y</a>` then `{% spaceless %}` will remove the space between the inline elements `strong` and `a`, meaning the rendering will `XY` instead of the intended rendering of `X Y`  I would recommend using a more intelligent minifier such as [django-htmlmin](https://github.com/cobrateam/django-htmlmin) or [google pagespeed apache/nginx module](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-whitespace-collapse)

Comment: See : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/x9tF3RO3rFg TLDR : added by popular request to django, less efficient than Gzip or it could be worse than doing nothing, html code is not supposed to be read by human and django dev would supress it if they could.

Answer (score 2):

it would make sense to have a version of {%spaceless%} that cross boundaries (ala Ifs and Fors), bad sadly Django doesn't support this simple feature. I have a dynamic class that gets added by Me and there are dozens of lines in spaces (all spaces match up to the template). This shouldn't be too hard for the developers of Django to add. 
adding spaceless to each if would be extemely stupid.

if they are really worried, you could have a depth parameter as well.